# Capturing incoming tcp/ip packets

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

Can anyone give me an example of a wireshark filter for capturing incoming tcp/ip packets, and another for capturing incoming packets on a specific port?

Comment: You mean in the Wireshark Visual User Interface or using the command line?

Comment: Either would be fine, as long as I have a way to monitor the traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) you can find various examples.
For incoming ip packets:  `ip.src==1.2.3.4` or for packets on specific port `tcp.port eq 8080`  and you can combine queries with logical operators